# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0} \large \frac {\sqrt{x}}{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Using L'Hospitals rule I keep on getting $\frac{0}{0}$... But Im not sure if this is correct?

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin x}$$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}x^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{\cos x}$$
  $$\frac{-\frac{1}{4}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{-\sin x}$$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)$, the limit does not exist.

Comment: @L.F. It isn't finite, but it exists.

Comment: @GitGud Gosh I have been saying that for a very long time - I have always been told that the existence of a limit is equivalent to convergence. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @L.F. I've been told both. I'd rather use the terminolgy that implies that "$\infty$ is a limit".

Comment: @L.F.: It converges in the two-point [compactification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_%28mathematics%29) of $\mathbb{R}$, sometimes called the [Extended Reals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_line).

Comment: Git Gut has a point here, but Cauchy did not consider infinity as an answer to a limit. In particular, the well known limit law, "product of the limits is the limit of the products" does not apply if we allow one of the limits to be infinity. However, if we rule out infinity as a "temporary answer" to a limit, then there are limits then cannot be calculated that do have a finite answer in the end. The space is not enough to write examples of both situations, but I discusss this extensively in my Calc class. So rule of thumb: Some flexibility as well as common sense is needed here.

Answer (score 7):

After applying L'Hospital's once, reevaluate: it is no longer in an indeterminate form.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sqrt x}{\sin x} \quad \overset{L'H}= \quad \lim_{x\to 0} \frac 12 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt x\cos x}$$

The right-sided limit (approaching $0$ from the right) exists, and $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac 12 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt x\cos x}\to \infty$. But the left-sided limit (approaching $x$ from the left) is not defined, i.e., the limit does not exist.

ADDED: Recall that we can apply L'Hospital *if and only if* the limit evaluates to an indeterminate form. And after applying it once, with the posted limit, we obtain a form of $1/0$, which is not indeterminate.

Comment: Your answer is for limit as $x\to0^+$, while you're talking as it as a two-sided limit. The two-sided limit asked in question doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** $$\lim _{ x\to 0 } \frac { \sqrt { x }  }{ \sin  x } =\lim _{ x\to 0 } \frac { \sqrt { x }  }{ x } \frac { x }{ \sin  x } =\lim _{ x\to 0 } \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { x }  } $$

Answer (score 2):

The given limit is equivalent to:
$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
since:
 $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{\sin x} =1$$
we see the limit exist for $x≥ 0$ and
 $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \to \infty $$

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the problem, you can already say that the limit does not exist. The limit is two-sided, and approaching zero from the left side cannot be done, domain issue of the square root.